# Relation between conditional entropies with a function of a random variable

Tags: entropy

Notation:

```
X,Y - random variables
f() - a function
H() - entropy
```

We know that $H(f(X)) \le H(X)$ (see e.g. [Entropy of functions of a random variable](http://www.ece.tufts.edu/~maivu/ES250/HW1_ES250_sol.pdf))

I read in a paper that $H(Y|f(X)) \ge H(Y|X)$.
But I couldn't prove it:
$$
H(Y|X)    = H(X|Y)    - H(X)    + H(Y) \\
H(Y|f(X)) = H(f(X)|Y) - H(f(X)) + H(Y) \\
H(Y|X) - H(Y|f(X)) = [H(X|Y) - H(f(X)|Y)] + [H(f(X)) - H(X)] \\
H(X|Y) \ge H(f(X)|Y) \implies H(X|Y) - H(f(X)|Y) \ge 0 \\
H(X) \ge H(f(X)) \implies H(f(X)) - H(X) \le 0 \\
\implies H(Y|X) \lessgtr H(Y|f(X))
$$
I.e., we have a sum of two differences, one positive and the other negative, so it's unknown what the sign of the result will be, i.e. $H(Y|f(X)) \lessgtr H(Y|X)$.

Please advise where I'm wrong and how to prove the claim or whether the claim in the paper is wrong.

Comment: The claim is true. This is a generalization of the inequality $H(Y\mid X) \leq H(Y)$, which is proved in [this document](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/mutual2.pdf). The proof is not straightforward.

Comment: Thx. I went over the proof and understand it.
How does the claim follow?
Also, where am I wrong in my reasoning showing that the relationship is indetermined?

Comment: I don't think the claim follows from the particular case. But the proof should be similar. You're not wrong, but the inequalities you use do not allow to prove the claim.

Comment: Thx.  

I created a small counter-example showing the claim fails:  
X∈{1,2,3}, ∀X:P(X)=1/3, f(X)=[1,1,2], ∀X:P(f(X))=1/2, Y∈{1,2}  
P(Y|X=1)=[.1,.9], P(Y|X=2)=[.2,.8], P(Y|X=3)=[.3,.7], H(Y|X)=0.69  
P(Y|f(X)=1)=[.1,.9], P(Y|f(X)=2)=[.2,.8], H(Y|f(X))=0.59  
H(Y|X)>H(Y|f(X))

Comment: This claim is expected: given less information, the entropy is larger. What is $f$ in your counter-example ? It's not possible to send the law $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ to the law $(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: P_x(1) = P_x(2) = P_x(3) = 1/3; z=f(X); f(1)=1, f(2)=1, f(3)=2; P_z(1)=P_z(2)=1/2

Comment: No, you cannot set an arbitrary law to $f(X)$; its law is given by $\Pr(f(X)=1) = \Pr(X=1 \text{ or } X=2) = 2/3$ and $\Pr(f(X)=2) = \Pr(X=3) = 1/3$.

Comment: This claim is true and well-known. It is proved in Billingsley's book, "Ergodic theory and information".

Comment: Thx. It's property A3 on p.78 in the 1965 edition. Need to go through the proof which isn't trivial

Comment: It holds if f(X) ⊂ X

Comment: Also here https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/it.pdf, Lemma 2.5.2 p.37, 5th relation